# IE 10 keyup/keydown not firing with jQuery 1.10.1

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

Using jQuery 1.10.1, for some reason this isn't working in IE10 but works fine everywhere else (read Chrome, Firefox). Discovered this bug while creating a fiddle for an answer on Stack Overflow.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="anId" />
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#anId").keyup(function(){
        alert(1);
    });
});
```

Neither does this:

```
$(function(){
$("#anId").keydown(function(){
       alert(1);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FBnUB/1/)
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FBnUB/2/)

Comment: @AKA Did you check in IE10 ?

Comment: Console say anything weird?

Comment: Does it work if you use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`?  Because an alert disturbs the flow of user interaction events (because the alert changes window focus, etc), that may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in JQuery 1.10.1.  You should be seeing a security error in your console on IE.  This is fixed in JQuery 1.10.2.

See this jquery bug:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13980

From the bug:

> In IFrame where the content is loaded from the external domain, JQuery v1.10.1 fails to load in Opera 12.15 and IE 10 with error "Unhandled error: Security error: attempted to read protected variable" on the line 1513.